# how to show an alert box In javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got 2 text-boxes wherein the user has to enter a number. If the user enters a letter, an alert box should appear, indicating that only numbers are to be entered.

How can that be done in JavaScript?

Updates:

This is the code I used for the alert box:

```
function checkIfNumeric(total) {
    if (isNaN(total)) {
        alert ("not a number!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How about you try it before asking?

Comment: copy and paste title of question into google, that's how

Comment: @A.O. LOL, I'm crying right now.

Comment: And I really hope @arch doesn't get his measly 2 rep for that useless edit lol

Comment: @arch "I've got 2 text-boxs `in` which the user has to enter a number"

Comment: @PaulG That is very careless of me. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @A.O. I saw one user edit a post by changing `etc...` to `etc..`, yeah he removed a dot.

Comment: it sounds like you need to use the onkeyup event to monitor changes to the textboxes

Comment: in all seriousness, you should spend some good quality reading time here http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: @PaulG Just saw your second edit. Thanks man. Corrected that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the user has entered a number or not, you could use `isNaN`:

```
function foo() {
 var a = document.getElementById("inputField").value;
 if (isNaN(a)) 
 {
 alert("Must input numbers");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("its a number");
 }
}
```

where inputField is the ID of your input field. Of course you can use

```
 if (isNaN(a)) 
 {
 alert("Must input numbers");
 }
 else
 {
 alert("its a number");
 }
```

in any context, you don't have to place it in an apart function like I did here.
**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m5cTr/1/

Comment: what do you mean with calculating?

Comment: your comment is not readable its a complete mess of code and text

Comment: @user3443845 I have updated my answer and added a JSFiddle. Does it work for you now?

Comment: i didnt seen yet where is that?

Comment: Where is **what**...?

Comment: i think tha problem is you created the foo as function of button click

Comment: It's pretty easy - change the name of the function and the onclick attribute of the button! :D, and please mark it as accepted if it works (you can modify the function and variable name to anything you want ofcourse)

Comment: what do you mean? change the name of the function AND of the onclick attribute and it works!

Comment: i mean the two input has some calculation, so I created a on-click event which calculate the amount,,BUT WHEN I CHANGE THAT name to this i dont think the main caculation going to work

Comment: cou can use the `isNaN(variable)` also in another function ofcourse. I've updated my answer also. and since it works, please mark it as accepted!

Comment: what do you mean with redirecting to "the next page"

Comment: i mean it showing the error message but when i click the ok button for the javascript.. it going to my other page that was linked ..

Comment: it should go to other page when the user enter number,, but its going when the error message was clicked ok by me

Comment: `if (isNaN(a)) 
 {
 alert("Must input numbers");
 }
 else
 {
 document.location.href="http://www.example.com/"; //you can use any url here
 }`
**look here:** http://jsfiddle.net/m5cTr/3/

Comment: no now its not showing the error message it just going to the example page